# Scala self not recognized from case class inside a Trait

Tags: scala, traits, self, case-class

Why self symbol is not recognized in here? I'm using Scala 2.12.

```
trait Parsers[ParseError, Parser[+_]] {

  def or[A](s1: Parser[A], s2: Parser[A]): Parser[A]

  case class ParserOps[A](p: Parser[A]) {
    def |[B>:A](p2: Parser[B]): Parser[B] = self.or(p,p2)
    def or[B>:A](p2: => Parser[B]): Parser[B] = self.or(p,p2)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't defined `self`. Define it and it will work.

```
trait Parsers[ParseError, Parser[+_]] { self => 

  def or[A](s1: Parser[A], s2: Parser[A]): Parser[A]

  case class ParserOps[A](p: Parser[A]) {
    def |[B>:A](p2: Parser[B]): Parser[B] = self.or(p,p2)
    def or[B>:A](p2: => Parser[B]): Parser[B] = self.or(p,p2)
  }

}
```

Comment: As an addition, here's a link to the relevant doc for this feature (https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/self-types.html)